# Macros in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

This might be a multi-part question based off of the responses, but as of now I am trying to learn how to program with Macros in excel. I know how to use a macro to set any given cell equal to a hard coded value (Like Cells(2,3).Value = 3) and I know how to put a general equation into a cell

(Cells(2,3).FORMULA = "=istext(8,8)"). But when I try to add put an if statement into a cell using excel the machine flips out since it can't handle the double quote.

What I have is Cells(2,3).Formula = "=if (X2 = 1, "You got it", "Missed again")"

What do I need to do in order to get the macro to be happy?

Thanks

(Note in this example things might be a little off since I am not copying and pasting from my work computer. For example maybe on one of my above equations I am missing a comma or something, people have reviewed my work and that is semantics is not a problem)

Comment: Try performing such an action with the Macro Recorder running, and then inspect the VBA code generated. Although the generated code is often full of unnecessary cell activations, it is otherwise quite informative. A great way to learn your way around the VBA libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a string, you want to turn a double quote into a double double quote, for example:

```
Cells(2,3).Formula = "=if(x2 = 1, ""You got it"", ""Missed again"")"
```

Note also that you don't want a space after the if and before the bracket.
Hope this helps.